# Get info from config using LIST java

Tags: java, list, search, config

i need to get specific info from my config, it looks like this:

```
name: test
locationA: -453.0,8.0,-187.0
locationB: -462.0,3.0,-174.0
prisonfile: ./plugins/JB/test.prison
prisons:
- 622.0,4.0,-456.0
- 611.0,4.0,-456.0
- 588.0,4.0,-867.0
- 597.0,4.0,-867.0
- -454.0,4.0,-176.0
- -460.0,4.0,-176.0
police:
- 611.0,4.0,-471.0
- 622.0,4.0,-471.0
- 597.0,4.0,-877.0
- 588.0,4.0,-877.0
- -460.0,4.0,-186.0
- -454.0,4.0,-186.0
open: true
```

And my code looks something like this:
HashMap prison = plugin.prisons.getPrison(world.getName(), false);

```
    File configFile = new File(prison.get("config").toString());
    FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);
    String listName = "police";
    List<String> list = config.getStringList(listName);
```

now if i print out list it just wrote down all coordinations from list POLICE, yea its good but what i need is to get always just 1 random  coordination, for example -454.0,4.0,-186.0.

I can imagine its noobish question but i cant fix it by my self for pretty long so hope for some help

Comment: generate a random index up to the list size and get the element at that index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in list can be accessed through index like:

```
List<String> list = config.getStringList(listName);
list.get(0); // Will return first element.
```

Or Iterate over the complete list, like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    String s = list.get(i);

    if(s.equals("abc")){
         // Do whatever required based on comparing element value.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i hope for something like a check how many  coordinations are in config and random get 1 of them. Can u help with it?

Comment: You can iterate through list and getSize() will return you size of list. While iterating you can get Element and perform checks.